# Adding 'n' values in list using for-loop and step-loop for that 'n' values in python

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, amazon-product-api

I have recently started to work with python 2.7 .
i have some data which i am passing to product API of amazon, to make it a batch call i want to pass 10 values per call as that is the max IDs or keywords per batch call.

Here is a question that, how to pass only 10 values to the function. I have some 76 values(it may increase) in total which is a list  and 6 at the end.I can read values from list using *args but to get only 10 values how can i process it using for-loop statement or any loop.

I want to do something like this

```
data = rows_db
count = 76

for id in data[range start , count ]:
    ids = id #copy 10 values or less 
    foo(ids)
    start = start + 10 

def foo(*ids):
    #process and retrieve values
```

Comment: 1st: Don't call `foo` if it isn't defined yet (move `foo` up); 2nd: what is `data[range start , count ]`?

Comment: from the "data" which is a list containing all the (76)values copying from range of 0-10 , 11-20 and so on till 76.

edit : the function will be defined, just displaying here for an example :) @CodingLambdas

Comment: Ok, I already guessed it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```python
data_copy = list(data)  # you can replace any appearance of data_copy with data if you don't care if it is changed
while data_copy:  # this is equivalent to: while len(data_copy) != 0:
    to = min(10, len(data_copy))  # If there are less then 10 entries left, the length will be smaller than ten, so that it is either 10 or the (smaller) length. This is the amount of data that's processed
    f(data_copy[:to])  # make the function call with any value up to 'to'
    del data_copy[:to]  # delete the data, because we already processed it
```

This:

```python
def f(x): print(x)
data = list(range(53))  # list from 0 (included) to 52 (included)
# here is the top part
```

yields the expected output of

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
[40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
[50, 51, 52]
```

Comment: hello thanks alot i tried this with 39 values and getting incorrect output, is it not getting deleted

39
10

39
10

29
10

19
9

9

Comment: Wait, I think I might be able to fix that.

Comment: let me check  . give me a minute :)

Comment: hey , thanks a ton sir, its working as i wanted.

p.s wish could vote your answer, don't have enough reputations! 

also if you could upvote my question

Comment: No problem. I like to help. (That's one reason why I am here, apparently)